# Passing variable changes between threads in Python functions [Beginner]

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, loops, multiprocessing

So I have this code:

```
import time
import threading

bar = False

def foo():
    while True:
        if bar == True:
            print "Success!"
        else:
            print "Not yet!"
    time.sleep(1)

def example():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        bar = True

t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
t1.start()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=example)
t2.start()
```

I'm trying to understand why I can't get `bar` to `=` to `true`.. If so, then the other thread should see the change and write `Success!`

Comment: The `bar` in the two functions are not in the same scope. You should deal with scopes before you learn multithreading. In any case there should be mutual-resource constructs you can use for threads.

Comment: Indentation in `time.sleep(1)` is wrong. I think is was intended to be inside the while loop.

Answer (score 11):

`bar` is a global variable. You should put `global bar` inside `example()`:

```
def example():
    global bar
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        bar = True
```

- When **reading** a variable, it is first searched inside the function and if not found, outside. That's why it's not necessary to put `global bar` inside `foo()`.
- When a variable is **assigned** a value, it is done locally inside the function unless the `global` statement has been used. That's why it's necessary to put `global bar` inside `example()`

Answer (score 1):

You must specify 'bar' as global variable. Otherwise 'bar' is only considered as a local variable.

```
def example():
    global bar
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        bar = True
```